# Include only a small part of another script with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, include

are there a way that I can include only a small part of a script like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<div class="HelloWorld">' , $content );
$second_step = explode('</div class="HelloWorld">' , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

...But just with Javascript instead of PHP?

Thanks

Comment: using jquery.fn.html method $('.Hellwold').html()

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is getting the innerHTML of the div helloworld.using [jquery.fn.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead.

```js
console.log($(".HelloWorld").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="HelloWorld"><span>foo</span>bar</div>
```

OR you can do it with DOM api directly which HTMLElement has an `innerHTML` attribute:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".HelloWorld").innerHTML);
```

```html
 <div class="HelloWorld"><span>foo</span>bar</div>
```